# make `pip` use not-default python3.7

Tags: 16.04, python3, pip, python-2.7

I know this is a question similar to those already asked many times, but I still can not get a trustable solution.
I have many versions of python installed on my Ubuntu 16.04, from the 2.7 to the latest 3.7.4.

Default is the 2.7. I know I should not change the default, because others have done it and it brought issues as serious as system breakdowns.
However, I have to install a software through pip:

```
pip install damn_software
```

which requires python >= 3.6

```
:~$ pip install damn_software
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support

Collecting damn_software
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cc/19/632db1d5095a35b08ba000d63e1ceffaf56c730dbd259f021e1fb7a75f68/damn_software-0.1.8.tar.gz
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /usr/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-qDPgIM/damn_software/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-qDPgIM/damn_software/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
     cwd: /tmp/pip-install-qDPgIM/damn_software/
Complete output (1 lines):
ERROR: Python (3, 5) or later is required by software-helpers for damn_software
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I do not know how to workaround this? Maybe a symlink?

**EDIT**: I had to run the following additional commands before the installation went through:

```
python3.7 -m pip install --user --upgrade pip
python3.7 -m pip install your_packages
sudo apt install python3.7-dev
```

Comment: Did you try `pip3 install your_software`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just run the Python interpreter of the version you want, with `pip` as module to execute, like:

```
python3.6 -m pip install some_package
```

That way you can be 100% sure the interpreter you launch your scripts with is the same as for which you manage pip packages. No system modifications necessary.

The `pip` executable is not exactly defined to be any fixed version anyway, whatever updates next would likely override it again. Plus it sometimes breaks for other reasons like version incompatibilities anyway. I'd usually not use it directly at all, except maybe for when you're in a venv (Python virtual environment) where it's exactly defined what it is.

Comment: `$ python3.7 -m pip install ligo-skymap
/usr/bin/python3.7: No module named pip` (while it was at least running before)

Comment: That means your 3.7 version of Python doesn't have a `pip` package installed yet. How to get `pip` for it depends on how you installed it. If you got it e.g. from the deadsnakes PPA, you can just `sudo apt install python3.7-pip` and it should start working that way.

Comment: I think (not sure though) that I have installed it through `sudo apt-get install python3.7`

Comment: Then please try `sudo apt install python3.7-pip` as I suggested.

Comment: Sorry, I had tried already: `E: Impossible to find the package python3.7-pip`. Perhaps a matter of repository?

Comment: Hmm, my fault. That package does indeed not exist, I remembered it incorrectly. Try and have a look at the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54633657/4464570

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96941/discussion-between-py-ser-and-byte-commander).

Answer (score 2):

install pip3 by

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

then add this line to ~/.bashrc (or equivalent)

```
alias pip=pip3
```

source the bashrc

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

now you can do

```
pip install damn_software
```

It will use python3 as default

alternatively you can use [conda](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/) or [venv](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/) to install pip